# what the URL for your bot's messaging endpoint?

Tags: azure, bots

what the URL for your bot's messaging endpoint while registering your bot in azure

Answer (score 0):

> what the URL for your bot's messaging endpoint while registering your bot in azure

You could get the answer from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart).

```
https://your_bots_hostname/api/messages
```